# AWK - taking incorrect parameters when using $1, $2 etc

Tags: bash, awk

I am using a script which launches with a number parameters assigned to it. For example, you can imagine that this is what I am doing when launching the script from the command line:

```
script.sh "/tmp" "/apps" "/var".
```

This script runs through a system which I will not delve into detail about. This system is the cause of my problem but I am powerless to make any changes to this.

So, when I use `awk '{print $2}'`, I receive the 2nd parameter I passed to my script ("/apps") rather than the field in the command I am running.

My question: is there any alternative notation that I can use in AWK except for $1, $2 etc to signify field values?

UPDATE:

Here is an example of one command within the script:

```
df | grep -e /$ | awk '{print $3/1024}'.
```

This problem is, the 3rd parameter is populated by "/var" as mentioned above

Comment: Without looking at the script we can only make guesses.

Comment: Are you using single quotes to quote the awk script or double quotes? Where does the awk input come from?

Comment: You're using double instead of single quotes or `eval`ing the command line or something to strip off the script delimiter quotes. The command you posted would NOT behave the way you describe as-is, post your real script for more help.

Comment: for command `df | grep -e /$ | awk '{print $3/1024}'` you got `/var` as `$3` but here it's working for me.

Comment: It's quite clearly the system through which my scripts are running -- it's known as Tableaux. Thanks to everyone for helping.

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask this question in a Tableaux forum or add a Tableaux tag to this question if there is such a thing.

Comment: As its seen here, its not possible but still
`df | grep -e /$ | (awk '{print $3/1024}')`

awk statement in a subshell

Answer (score 0):

Try `\$1`, `\$2` etc. (The "system" seems to drop at least one level of quoting from the command, so let's add one.)